# R - ggplot - overlying line plot with single points, empty series for geom_points() causes error

Tags: r

**Problem with empty series for geom_point**

I am trying to create a repeatable routine for a line plot for simulated price series which are overlayed with points marking the buy (blue dots) and sell (red dots) points. 


In some cases there are no buy or sell points which creates an empty object for geom_point so that it gives and error and prevents completing the chart.


**Example which works (buy and sell points exist)**

```
Time <- c(seq(1,12,1))
Prices <- c(36.23, 35.87, 36.18, 36.54, 35.96, 36.68, 37.16, 37.69, 38.15, 38.61, 39.91, 40.45)
TradingPrice_BUY <- c(36.23,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
TradingPrice_SELL <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,39.91,NA)
Trades<-data.frame(Time ,Prices, TradingPrice_BUY, TradingPrice_SELL)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Trades,aes(x=Time,y=Prices,group=1)) + 
theme_bw() + geom_line() + xlab("Time") + ylab("Price") +
  geom_point(data=Trades, aes(x=Time,y=TradingPrice_BUY),color="blue",shape=19) + 
  geom_point(data=Trades, aes(x=Time,y=TradingPrice_SELL),color="red",shape=19)
```

**Example for the case where sell points don't exist 

Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale**

```
Time <- c(seq(1,12,1))
Prices <- c(36.23, 35.87, 36.18, 36.54, 35.96, 36.68, 37.16, 37.69, 38.15, 38.61, 39.91, 40.45)
TradingPrice_BUY <- c(36.23,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
TradingPrice_SELL <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Trades<-data.frame(Time ,Prices, TradingPrice_BUY, TradingPrice_SELL)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=Trades,aes(x=Time,y=Prices,group=1)) + 
theme_bw() + geom_line() + xlab("Time") + ylab("Price") +
  geom_point(data=Trades, aes(x=Time,y=TradingPrice_BUY),color="blue",shape=19) + 
  geom_point(data=Trades, aes(x=Time,y=TradingPrice_SELL),color="red",shape=19)
```

**I tried to work around it but got another error 

Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): x, y, group**

```
ggplot(data=Trades,aes(x=Time,y=Prices,group=1)) + 
theme_bw() +geom_line()+xlab("Time") + ylab("Price")+
geom_point(data=subset(Trades,!is.na(Trades$TradingPrice_BUY)),aes(x=Time,y=TradingPrice_BUY),color="blue",shape=19) + 
  geom_point(data=subset(Trades,is.na(Trades$TradingPrice_BUY)), aes(x=1,y=Prices[1]),color=NA) +
  geom_point(data=subset(Trades,!is.na(Trades$TradingPrice_SELL)), aes(x=Time,y=TradingPrice_SELL),color="red",shape=19) +
  geom_point(data=subset(Trades,is.na(Trades$TradingPrice_SELL)),aes(x=1,y=Prices[1]),color=NA)
```

How to work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When plotting with `ggplot`, you need to keep your data in a "tidy" format for things to work nicely. Rather than adding different layers for different point, you should reshape your data and let the aesthetics takes care of formatting for you. Here I used `reshape2::melt` to "tidy" up your data. For example

```
point_data <- na.omit(reshape2::melt(Trades[c(1,3,4)], "Time"))
ggplot(data=Trades,aes(x=Time, y=Prices)) + 
    theme_bw() + geom_line() + xlab("Time") + ylab("Price") +
    geom_point(data=point_data, aes(x=Time, y=value, color=variable), shape=19) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=c(
        "TradingPrice_BUY"="blue", 
        "TradingPrice_SELL"="red"), guide=FALSE)
```

This should work fine